# Binary heap - Find number of nodes at a height

Tags: binary-search-tree, binary-heap

I have been struggling with this for several hours now, and I can't seem to find the answers here either. (there are many posts about Binary Heap, but I did not this particular problem).

The problem is:

**For a Binary Heap with 1492 nodes, the number of nodes of height two is _*187*_.**

I understand that with 1492 nodes, the binary heap has the depth log(1492)/log(2) = 10
height two should have 2^(10-2) nodes which should be 256

Why is the answer 187?

Thank you

Comment: With 1492 nodes, it's _not_ a full binary tree.

Comment: so 256 - 187 = 69 which means 69 are missing at that height. How can I calculate the number of missing nodes at a height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone needs to know. I found out the formula is n / 2^(h+1), so 1492 / 2^(2+1) = 186.5.