# What are the number of nodes at height h?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, tree, heap, binary-tree

Could someone explain the equation `n/(2^(h+1))` used to find the numbers of nodes at height h?

With a 3 node tree:

```
 4    h=1
2 3   h=0
```

for h=0 which is 2 nodes, the equation gives 3/(2^(0+1))=3/2^1=1.5

What does that mean? How is this correct, isn't the equation supposed to give the maximum numbers of nodes at height 0, which is 2, not 1.5?

This equation is from Introduction to algorithms
http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms

Here are more information about the equation and where I've found it mentioned:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6405/maximum-number-of-nodes-with-height-h
https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ee608/handouts/hw4s.pdf  #5

Comment: What kind of tree is this?  How are elements added?

Comment: Please don't crosspost.  http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/what-are-the-number-of-nodes-at-height-h

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary heap - Find number of nodes at a height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539689/binary-heap-find-number-of-nodes-at-a-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misread the formula. It's not just *n*/2<sup>*h*+1</sup>, it's ⌈*n*/2<sup>*h*+1</sup>⌉ (the square brackets with no "feet" are the notation for the ceiling function, which returns the smallest integer that is greater than its argument).

```
ceil(3/2^(0+1)) = ceil(3/2) 
                = ceil(1.5)
                = 2
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, ty

Answer (score 0):

In a full binary tree(a tree in which all levels are full)
there are ceil(n/2) leaves. So tree is basically like
 `1 2 4 8 .... Ceil(n/2)`.As in full binary tree.
`number nodes at height h = 2 * number nodes at height h-1`.
That just implies that to reach level h, you have to divide number of leaves h times with 2.Thus,

`number of nodes at height h in a full binary tree and maximum number of nodes at height h in complete binary tree(or almost complete binary tree) = ceil(n/2^(h+1)).`